# How can I show the amount saved in magento 2

Tags: php, magento-2.0, special-price

I am trying to display amount saved on the catalogue page for a magento 2.0.2 website. However I'm not getting the calculation result displayed. I just get an empty space. I am editing the final_price.phtml in my theme file. Please can I get some advice on what I am doing wrong. I can't find any information from searches as most results are for magento 1 and the codes are throwing errors This is what my code looks like in the section which i am trying to do the calculations.

```
<span class="special-price"><span class="only-text">Only: </span>
    <?php echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
        'display_label'     => __('Special Price'),
        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
        'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
        'include_container' => true,
        'schema' => $schema
    ]); ?>
</span>
<br>
<span class="old-price"><span class="rrp-text">RRP: </span>
    <?php echo $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [
        'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
        'price_type'        => 'oldPrice',
        'include_container' => true,
        'skip_adjustments'  => true
    ]); ?>
</span>
<span class="saving-price"><span class="saving-text">Saving: </span>
<?php
$wasPrice = $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), []);
$nowPrice = $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), []);
  if ($nowPrice < $wasPrice){
    $saving = $wasPrice - $nowPrice; 
    echo $saving;
  }
?>
</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue on category and search results pages on Magento 2. Here's what I eventually figured out. Hope it helps! (Note: this all falls within the **foreach** loop which iterates through each **$_product** within **$_productCollection**):

```
<?php
$regprice = $_product->getPrice();
$specialprice = $_product->getSpecialPrice();
$yousave = number_format((float)($regprice - $specialprice), 2, '.', '');
$yousavepct = number_format((float)(100*(($regprice - $specialprice)/$regprice)), 0);

if($yousave > 0): ?>
    <p class="you-save-statement">You save: $<?php echo $yousave; ?> (<?php echo $yousavepct; ?>%)</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```